# How to sec color of each bars of histogram in ATAS c#

Tags: c#, histogram, visualization, stock, economics

I've tried to draw Weis Wave Histogram in ATAS using C#.
But, in C# code, can't set each bar's color.
How can I do this?

I've tried to use sample code provided by ATAS, but it was old version.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and ATAS 6.1(this is the last version).
Please Help me.

Comment: Please provide your current code so that additions and changes can be suggested.